# How can I get the symbol "plus inside triangle" and "plus inside downtriangle" without interfere with the other symbols I am using?

Tags: symbols

I want the symbols "plus inside triangle" and "plus inside downtriangle", which somehow correspond to \triangleplus and \downtriangleplus (though there seems to be no such available command), respectively. But I also use the symbol \diamondplus, for which I need the package MnSymbol. Thus I cannot use \triangleplus (for which, the package stix is needed) in the meanwhile. So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can load both packages if you want, with symbol packages this is usually not a problem.

For the upside down triangle with plus you can define your own command where you rotate the original command by 180 degrees.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\downtriangleplus{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath{\triangleplus}}}
\begin{document}
$\triangleplus \diamondplus \downtriangleplus$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It seems not work...    My preamble is as follows. Please see if there is any mistake.                                                                                                                       \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\downtriangleplus{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath{\triangleplus}}}

Comment: Now I know where the problem is. It works if I delete \usepackage{amssymb}! Many thanks Marjin! But the sizes of \triangleplus and \downtriangleplus are much bigger than \diamondplus. If only their sizes are the same!

Comment: `MnSymbol` is not compatible with `amssymb`, as stated at the start of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf). But you can probably lift just the one symbol, I'll check if I can make that work.

Comment: Thank you Marjin. A further question: do you know how to make the sizes of the three symbols the same? There's a big difference in size.